# Avoid a table cell to be multi-lined

Tags: tables

I'm having this table that I've got with the help of my friends here. I want to make sure that no cell of this table (particularly, cell of "Description" column) get multi-lined (they only cover a single line of text)
I appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow,}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}% had to be last in preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \small
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{List of SWAT parameters evaluated for sensitivity analysis in the ECW.}
       \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                    ll
                                    >{\RaggedRight}p{15em}
                                    lll
                                    @{}}
         \toprule
          &
           Parameter &
           Description &
           Units &
           \multicolumn{1}{p{2.07em}}{LB} &
           \multicolumn{1}{p{1.855em}}{UB}
           \\
       \midrule
         1 & ALPHA\_BF &
           Base flow alpha factor for recession constant\tnote{(a,b)} &
           day & 0 & 1 \\
         2 & CANMX &
           Maximum canopy storage\tnote{(c)} &
           mm & 0 & 10 \\
         3 & CH\_KI &
           Fraction change in hydraulic conductivity in tributary channels\tnote{(d)} &
            \si{\mm\per\hour} & 0 & 300 \\
         4 & CH\_KII &
           Fraction change in hydraulic conductivity in the main channel\tnote{(d)} &
             \si{\mm\per\hour} & -0.01 & 500 \\
         5 & CH\_NI &
           Manning’s n value for the tributary channels\tnote{(d)} &
          – & 0.01 & 0.3 \\
         6 & CH\_NII &
           Manning’s n value for the main channels\tnote{(d)} &
          – & 0.01 & 0.3 \\
         7 & CN2 &
           Initial SCS runoff curve number for moisture condition II\tnote{(e)} &
           \% & -10 & 10 \\
         8 & DDRAIN &
           Depth to subsurface drain\tnote{(f)} &
           mm & 500 & 1500 \\
         9 & ESCO &
           Soil evaporation compensation factor\tnote{(c)} &
          – & 0.01 & 1 \\
         10 & GDRAIN
         & Drain tile lag time\tnote{(f)} &
           h & 0 & 48 \\
         11 & GW\_DELAY &
           Groundwater delay time\tnote{(b)} &
           day & 0 & 90 \\
         12 & GWQMN &
           Threshold depth of water in the shallow aquifer required for return flow to occur\tnote{(b)} &
           mm & 0 & 4000 \\
         13 & SFTMP &
           Snow temperature\tnote{(g)} &
           \si{\celsius} & -5 & 5 \\
         14 & SMFMN &
           Minimum melt rate for snow\tnote{(g)} &
           \si{\mm\per\celsius\per\day} & 0 & 10 \\
         15 & SMFMX &
           Maximum melt rate for snow\tnote{(g)} &
           \si{\mm\per\celsius\per\day} & 0 & 10 \\
         16 & SMTMP &
           Snow melt base temperature\tnote{(g)}&
           \si{\celsius} & -5 & 5 \\
         17 & SNO50COV &
           Snow water equivalent that correspond to 50\,\% snow cover\tnote{(g)} &
           mm & 0 & 0.9 \\
         18 & SNOCOVMX &
           Minimum snow water content that corresponds to 100\,\% snow cover\tnote{(g)} &
           mm & 0 & 650 \\
         19 & SOL\_AWC &
           Available soil water capacity\tnote{(h)} &
           \% & -10 & 20 \\
         20 & SURLAG &
           Surface runoff lag time\tnote{(e)} &
           day & 1 & 12 \\
         21 & TIMP &
           Snow pack temperature lag factor\tnote{(g)} &
         – & 0.01 & 1 \\
         \bottomrule
         \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item The process represented by the parameters are (a) baseflow, (b) groundwater, (c) evapotranspiration, (d) channel flow, (e) surface runoff, (f) water management, (g) snow and (h) soil water processes.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can wrap every table entry into `\mbox{}`

Comment: So you want every column to be stretched so wide there are no multilined cells?

Comment: replace `>{\RaggedRight}p{15em}` (multiline entries of width 15em) by `l` (single line entries)

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Yes exactly, I need to stretch them all, and fit the table to the width of lines.

Answer (score 1):

The only realistic way to avoid all linebreaks in all columns is to switch the table to landscape mode, say, with the use of a `sidewaystable` environment.

That said, I honestly can't see what's supposed to be so bad about letting the text in the "Description" column break across two or more lines, in order to make the table fit in portrait page orientation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb, adjustbox, siunitx, rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[flushleft,para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \small
  \caption{List of SWAT parameters evaluated for sensitivity analysis in the ECW.}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} llll >{$}r<{$} r @{}}
  \toprule
  & Parameter & Description & Units 
  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{LB} & UB \\
  \midrule
     1 & ALPHA\_BF &
       Base flow alpha factor for recession constant\tnote{(a,b)} &
       day & 0 & 1 \\
     2 & CANMX &
       Maximum canopy storage\tnote{(c)} &
       mm & 0 & 10 \\
     3 & CH\_KI &
       Fraction change in hydraulic conductivity in tributary channels\tnote{(d)} &
       \si{\mm\per\hour} & 0 & 300 \\
     4 & CH\_KII &
       Fraction change in hydraulic conductivity in the main channel\tnote{(d)} &
       \si{\mm\per\hour} & -0.01 & 500 \\
     5 & CH\_NI &
       Manning's n value for the tributary channels\tnote{(d)} &
       -- & 0.01 & 0.3 \\
     6 & CH\_NII &
       Manning's n value for the main channels\tnote{(d)} &
       -- & 0.01 & 0.3 \\
     7 & CN2 &
       Initial SCS runoff curve number for moisture condition II\tnote{(e)} &
       \% & -10 & 10 \\
     8 & DDRAIN &
       Depth to subsurface drain\tnote{(f)} &
       mm & 500 & 1500 \\
     9 & ESCO &
       Soil evaporation compensation factor\tnote{(c)} &
       -- & 0.01 & 1 \\
     10 & GDRAIN & 
        Drain tile lag time\tnote{(f)} &
        h & 0 & 48 \\
     11 & GW\_DELAY &
        Groundwater delay time\tnote{(b)} &
        day & 0 & 90 \\
     12 & GWQMN &
        Threshold depth of water in the shallow aquifer required for return flow to occur\tnote{(b)} &
        mm & 0 & 4000 \\
     13 & SFTMP &
        Snow temperature\tnote{(g)} &
        \si{\celsius} & -5 & 5 \\
     14 & SMFMN &
        Minimum melt rate for snow\tnote{(g)} &
        \si{\mm\per\celsius\per\day} & 0 & 10 \\
     15 & SMFMX &
        Maximum melt rate for snow\tnote{(g)} &
        \si{\mm\per\celsius\per\day} & 0 & 10 \\
     16 & SMTMP &
        Snow melt base temperature\tnote{(g)}&
        \si{\celsius} & -5 & 5 \\
     17 & SNO50COV &
        Snow water equivalent that correspond to 50\,\% snow cover\tnote{(g)} &
        mm & 0 & 0.9 \\
     18 & SNOCOVMX &
        Minimum snow water content that corresponds to 100\,\% snow cover\tnote{(g)} &
        mm & 0 & 650 \\
     19 & SOL\_AWC &
        Available soil water capacity\tnote{(h)} &
        \% & -10 & 20 \\
     20 & SURLAG &
        Surface runoff lag time\tnote{(e)} &
        day & 1 & 12 \\
     21 & TIMP &
        Snow pack temperature lag factor\tnote{(g)} &
        -- & 0.01 & 1 \\
     \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}     

     \footnotesize
     \smallskip

     The processes represented by the parameters are: 
      \textsuperscript{(a)}\,baseflow, 
      \textsuperscript{(b)}\,groundwater, 
      \textsuperscript{(c)}\,evapo\-transpiration, 
      \textsuperscript{(d)}\,channel flow, 
      \textsuperscript{(e)}\,surface runoff, 
      \textsuperscript{(f)}\,water management, 
      \textsuperscript{(g)}\,snow, and 
      \textsuperscript{(h)}\,soil water processes.

\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```